# stack: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'account'). Next-auth Error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm using Next-auth with google provider for google login. The login works perfectly well when I click on the login button, but when the session expires or I logout manually and retry to login by clicking on the login again, I'm constantly getting the error which says

```
 [next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR]        
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'account') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'account')

  name: 'GetUserByAccountError',
  code: undefined
}
```

If I restart the terminal and do npm run dev then everything works fine( i.e i get the login session data).I'm facing this problem if I logout or if the session expires and I try to login again. In addition to the error I receive in the console I'm constantly redirected to `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/error`

This is my prisma model

```
model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId            String
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String? @db.Text
  access_token      String? @db.Text
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.Text
  session_state     String?
  user              User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
  @@index([userId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@index([userId])
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  // games         Game[]
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}
```

This is my authOptions function which I'm using in route.ts. The api folder structure is like this `api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import { authOptions } from "@/lib/nextAuth";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

The database I'm using is posgresql.
Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Please help.